# Fixing Combinatorica redefinition of Element

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

My code relies on version of `Element` which works like `MemberQ`, but when I load `Combinatorica`, `Element` gets redefined to work like `Part`. What is the easiest way to fix this conflict? Specifically, what is the syntax to remove Combinatorica's definition from `DownValues`? Here's what I get for `DownValues[Element]`

```
{HoldPattern[
   Combinatorica`Private`a_List \[Element] \
{Combinatorica`Private`index___}] :> 
  Combinatorica`Private`a[[Combinatorica`Private`index]], 
 HoldPattern[Private`x_ \[Element] Private`list_List] :> 
  MemberQ[Private`list, Private`x]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to prevent Combinatorica from installing the definition in the first place, you can achieve this result by loading the package for the first time thus:

```
Block[{Element}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]]
```

However, this will almost certainly make any Combinatorica features that depend upon the definition fail (which may or may not be of concern in your particular application).

Comment: All of the functions from "Algorithmic Graph Theory" part of Combinatorica seem to work OK without Element

Comment: nice trick, certainly has its uses - this incarnation did not cross my mind. Can be a great aid for a developer. The bad side is that it severely undermines reusability (meaning other users). For example, if the code that employs it is itself in a package, and the user is unaware that it uses Combinatorica. So, the user first loads this one, and then Combinatorica (which she happens to also need for something else). Since Combinatorica is already on the $ContextPath, it is not loaded second time, while parts of it are broken. Without knowing these details, this looks like a mystery.

Comment: But it seems that the root of the evil is in package code that overloads built-ins. I actually think that this is a very serious problem for large projects using multiple third-party packages - such bugs will be very hard to catch. At the very least, there must be a tool which monitors redefinitions of system symbols made during package imports, and reports potential conflicts. This could be achieved by overloading Set and SetDelayed, but it would be even better to have a built-in support for this, particularly because definitions can be created also at run-time, not just load-time.

Comment: @Yaroslav: upon some thinking about it, I found another unintrusive alternative: you can make your functions using Element HoldAll (or HoldFirst or HoldRest, whatever is suitable), so that possible definitions of Element (DownValues) will have no chance to fire. For example: ClearAll[f];SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]; f[Element[x_, y_List]] := x^2 /; MemberQ[y, x] - this does not care whether Element has any DownValues or not.

Comment: My problem was that the package I'm using "Element" was invoked as a function, so custom definition was needed. I guess the avoid this is to never redefine built-ins. As of version 8, I think it's a bad idea to have Combinatorica in ContextPath, it conflicts with many graph and group theory functions

Answer (score 3):

You can do several things. Let us introduce a convenience function

```
ClearAll[redef];
SetAttributes[redef, HoldRest];
redef[f_, code_] := (Unprotect[f]; code; Protect[f])
```

If you are sure about the order of definitions, you can do something like

```
redef[Element, DownValues[Element] = Rest[DownValues[Element]]]
```

If you want to delete definitions based on the context, you can do something like this:

```
redef[Element, DownValues[Element] = 
    DeleteCases[DownValues[Element],
          rule_ /; Cases[rule, x_Symbol /; (StringSplit[Context[x], "`"][[1]] === 
                 "Combinatorica"), Infinity, Heads -> True] =!= {}]]
```

You can also use a softer way - reorder definitions rather than delete:

```
redef[Element, DownValues[Element] = RotateRight[DownValues[Element]]]
```

There are many other ways of dealing with this problem. Another one (which I already recommended) is to use UpValues, if this is suitable. The last one I want to mention here is to  make a kind of custom dynamic scoping construct based on Block, and wrap it around your code. I personally find it the safest variant, in case if you want strictly your definition to apply (because it does not care about the order in which various definitions could have been created - it removes all of them and adds just yours). It is also safer in that outside those places where you want your definitions to apply (by "places" I mean parts of the evaluation stack), other definitions will still apply, so this seems to be the least intrusive way. Here is how it may look:

```
elementDef[] := Element[x_, list_List] := MemberQ[list, x];

ClearAll[elemExec];
SetAttributes[elemExec, HoldAll];
elemExec[code_] :=  Block[{Element},   elementDef[];   code];
```

Example of use:

```
In[10]:= elemExec[Element[1,{1,2,3}]]

Out[10]= True
```

Edit:

If you need to automate the use of Block, here is an example package to show one way how this can be done:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"]

var;
f1;
f2;

Begin["`Private`"];

(* Implementations of your functions *)

var = 1;
f1[x_, y_List] := If[Element[x, y], x^2];
f2[x_, y_List] := If[Element[x, y], x^3];

elementDef[] := Element[x_, list_List] := MemberQ[list, x];

(* The following part of the package is defined at the start and you don't 
   touch it any more, when adding new functions to the package *)

mainContext = StringReplace[Context[], x__ ~~ "Private`" :> x];

SetAttributes[elemExec, HoldAll];
elemExec[code_] := Block[{Element}, elementDef[]; code];

postprocessDefs[context_String] :=
  Map[
   ToExpression[#, StandardForm,
     Function[sym,DownValues[sym] = 
        DownValues[sym] /. 
          Verbatim[RuleDelayed][lhs_,rhs_] :> (lhs :> elemExec[rhs])]] &,
   Select[Names[context <> "*"], ToExpression[#, StandardForm, DownValues] =!= {} &]];

postprocessDefs[mainContext];

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

You can load the package and look at the DownValues for f1 and f2, for example:

```
In[17]:= DownValues[f1]

Out[17]= {HoldPattern[f1[Test`Private`x_,Test`Private`y_List]]:>
  Test`Private`elemExec[If[Test`Private`x\[Element]Test`Private`y,Test`Private`x^2]]}
```

The same scheme will also work for functions not in the same package. In fact, you could separate 
the bottom part (code-processing package) to be a package on its own, import it into any other 
package where you want to inject Block into your functions' definitions, and then just call something like  `postprocessDefs[mainContext]`, as above. You could make the function which makes definitions inside Block (`elementDef` here) to be an extra parameter to a generalized version of `elemExec`, which would make this approach more modular and reusable.

If you want to be more selective about the functions where you want to inject Block, this can also be done in various ways. In fact, the whole Block-injection scheme can be made cleaner then, but it will require slightly more care when implementing each function, while the above approach is completely automatic. I can post the code which will illustrate this, if needed.

One more thing: for the less intrusive nature of this method you pay a price - dynamic scope (Block) is usually harder to control than lexically-scoped constructs. So, you must know exactly the parts of evaluation stack where you want that to apply. For example, I would hesitate to inject Block into a definition of a higher order function, which takes some functions as parameters, since those functions may come from code that assumes other definitions (like for example Combinatorica` functions relying on overloaded Element). This is not a big problem, just requires care.

The bottom  line of this seems to be: try to avoid overloading built-ins if at all possible. In this case you faced this definitions clash yourself, but it would be even worse if the one who faces this problem is a user of your package (may be yourself a few months later), who wants to combine your package with another one (which happens to overload same system functions as yours). Of course, it also depends on who will be the users of your package - only yourself or potentially others as well. But in terms of design, and in the long term, you may be better off assuming the latter scenario from the start.

Comment: Block may be un-intrusive, but I I have a package which uses this custom version of "Element"...so I need to wrap any call to a function from that package inside Block, right?

Comment: All you have to do is to wrap Block around the highest -level function that uses others (assuming you have one, but this is a common practice), be it from the same package or not. Usually one can extract some minimal interface, which consists of not too many functions.You can also use meta-programming to do this automatically, see the update to my post. I actually do these sort of things sometimes: Mathematica dynamic meta-programming capabilities are so much more powerful than in many other languages, and I don' t know why people don't use them more often (is it a cultural thing?)

Answer (score 1):

To remove `Combinatorica`'s definition, use [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unset.html) or the equivalent form `=.`. The pattern to unset you can grab from the `Information` output you show in the question:

```
Unprotect[Element];
Element[a_List, {index___}] =.
Protect[Element];
```

The worry would be, of course, that `Combinatorica` depends internally on this ill-conceived redefinition, but you have reason to believe this to not be the case as the `Information` output from the redefined `Element` says:

> The use of the function
> Element in Combinatorica is now
> obsolete, though the function call
> Element[a, p] still gives the pth
> element of nested list a, where p is a
> list of indices.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I propose an entirely different approach than removing Element from DownValues. Simply use the full name of the Element function.

So, if the original is

```
System`Element[]
```

the default is now

```
Combinatorica`Element[]
```

because of loading the Combinatorica Package.

Just explicitly use

```
System`Element[]
```

wherever you need it. Of course check that System is the correct Context using the Context function:

```
Context[Element]
```

This approach ensures several things:

1. The Combinatorica Package will still work in your notebook, even if the Combinatorica Package is updated in the future
2. You wont have to redefine the Element function, as some have suggested
3. You can use the Combinatorica`Element function when needed

The only downside is having to explicitly write it every time.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. Your suggestion is fine when there is a shadowing problem (although hard-coding a context name impairs maintainability, it is probably ok for ``System` ``). But here, what ``Combinatorica` `` did was to modify the ``System`Element``, and that was also what the OP's custom code did. So, the problem is on the level of conflicting definitions for the same symbol, not conflicting symbols.